# PHP MYSQL could not connect (HY000/2002)

Tags: php, mysql

i was working on a website on a local server (WAMP) and php and database worked fine. but when i uploaded the site to the hosting server. and tried to login, the DB connection would not work. it gives me warnings when i use DB functions like `mysqli::mysqli()`.

the whole error is as follows:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2002): No connection could be made
because the target machine actively refused it. 
in D:\Hosting\XXXXX\html\raw\database\connect.php on line 9
```

continues

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: [2002] No connection could be made because
the target machine actively (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in     
D:\Hosting\XXXXX\html\raw\database\connect.php on line 9


Warning: mysqli::query() [mysqli.query]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in    
D:\Hosting\XXXXX\html\raw\functions\users.php on line 10
```

The php code for connect.php is:

```
<?php

    require_once 'Internal/Var.php';
    //mysql_connect(D_SERVER, D_USER, D_PASSWORD);
    //mysql_select_db(D_NAME);

    function create_connection()
    {
        $conn = new mysqli(D_SERVER, D_USER, D_PASSWORD, D_NAME);
        return $conn;
    }

    function close_connection(mysqli $con)
    {
        $con->close();
    }

?>
```

Comment: why are you replacing perfectly valid OOP interface with procedural mess ?

Comment: i am new to PHP. i was working on java before. can you give an example.

Comment: the problem is tcp/ip connection.

Comment: There is example on the [official PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php), read about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `username` and `password` for your `MySQLi` connection.

```
require_once 'Internal/Var.php';
// Remove the two procedural connection lines here

function create_connection()
{
    // Make sure D_SERVER, D_USER, D_PASSWORD, D_NAME have the correct values
    // These values are probably created in Internal/Var.php
    $conn = new mysqli(D_SERVER, D_USER, D_PASSWORD, D_NAME);

    return $conn;
}

function close_connection(mysqli $con)
{
    $con->close();
}
```

Comment: the error is abt the DB connection.i am still geting the errors abt DB functions..

Comment: After you set those constants like D_SERVER etc., what errors are you seeing? DB connection is the thing I'm trying to fix with my answer.